# Converting array of array to hash

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

How can I convert an array of arrays to a hash?

```
arr = [['me',1],['he',2],['she',3]]
```

I want to have

```
{'me':1,'he':2,'she':3}
```

my current solutions is

```
hsh={}
arr.each do |x| p hsh[x[0]] = x[1] end
hsh # => {'me':1,'he':2,'she':3}
```

but it looks ugly. My code works, but I am looking for a more convenient way to do it.

Comment: What are the values of `me`, `he`, `she`?

Comment: Have you tried running your code? What errors do you get?

Comment: @sawa its just a string

Comment: You have unmatched square brackets in your array.

Comment: Do you mean `arr = [ [:me,1], [:he,2], [:she,3] ]`?

Comment: Note that the correct syntax for using strings as keys is `{'key' => 1}`. `{key: 1}` or `{'key': 1}` is for symbols. It's not clear whether you are also trying to convert the strings to symbols.

Answer (score 1):

Try the `to_h` method

```
arr = [['me',1],['he',2],['she',3]]
arr.to_h
# => {'me' => 1, 'he' => 2, 'she' => 3}
```

Note that this won't turn the original strings into symbols. I'm not sure if that is part of your question. If so, you'll have to go with Sawa's solution.

Comment: The solution is not working please check the array once again and try this solution.

Comment: @Prity: Thanks, I copy/pasted the code from the question, which had an extra `]`. I've corrected the typo.

Answer (score 0):

```
arr.map{|k, v| [k.to_sym, v]}.to_h
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I think your array should be either this:

```
arr = [['me',1],[['he',2],['she',3]]]
```

OR

```
arr = [['me',1],['he',2],['she',3]]
```

There is some issue in number of '[' and ']'

One solution that will work for both is as follows:

```
hsh = Hash[*arr.flatten]
```